# WCF - MessageContract members (MessageBodyMember) ignored when deserialising

Tags: wcf, soap, deserialization

I am consuming a SOAP service, and successfully receiving a response.

Unfortunately, WCF isn't deserialising the members of the response POCO.

Using Diagnostics Tracing, I get the following error occurring for each member in the Response:

```
Description     An unrecognised element was encountered in the XML during deserialisation which was ignored.
Element         :partnerId
```

Please can you see where I am going wrong?

Here's the code:

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "https://foo.com/services/mediationV1/", ConfigurationName = "IPlatformPortType")]
public interface IPlatformPortType
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "https://foo.com/services/foo_bar_HeartBeatV1/", ReplyAction = "*")]
    HeartBeatResponse SendHeartBeat(HeartbeatRequest request);
}
```

**POCO Request**

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true,
    WrapperName = "foo_bar_HeartBeatRequest",
    WrapperNamespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/")]
public class HeartbeatRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/", Order = 0)]
    public string transactionId { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/", Order = 2)]
    public string partnerId { get; set; }
}
```

**SOAP Request**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">https://foo.com/services/foo_bar_HeartBeatV1/</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:73efa49e-f2b3-4f5d-b750-6784b1becfbc</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <foo_bar_HeartBeatRequest xmlns="https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/">
            <transactionId>f642df34-d328-4d76-9a9f-3cf64bdef71d</transactionId>
            <partnerId>bob</partnerId>
        </foo_bar_HeartBeatRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**POCO Response**

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true,
    WrapperName = "foo_bar_HeartBeatResponse",
    WrapperNamespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/")]
public class HeartBeatResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/", Order = 2)]
    public string transactionId { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/", Order = 3)]
    public int requestStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**SOAP Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b66497fd-4e95-458c-8772-c8bfc0decb51</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>urn:mediateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:73efa49e-f2b3-4f5d-b750-6784b1becfbc</wsa:RelatesTo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:foo_bar_HeartBeatResponse xmlns:ns="https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/">
            <transactionId>f642df34-d328-4d76-9a9f-3cf64bdef71d</transactionId>
            <requestStatus>1</requestStatus>
        </ns:foo_bar_HeartBeatResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Update**

As per @TomRedfern's comment, I tried swapping out all the MessageContract attributes with DataContract.

Unfortunately this takes away my ability to notify the seriliaser that the POCO is a *wrapper*, causing the SOAP to look like the following:

```
<s:Body>
    <SendHeartBeat xmlns="https://foo.com/services/fooV1/">
        <request xmlns:b="https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <b:transactionId>7085587a-4275-49ad-9aa9-5b413afcbe62</b:transactionId>
            <b:partnerId>bob</b:partnerId>
        </request>
    </SendHeartBeat>
</s:Body>
```

Notice the name of the node is now the name of the Operation (SendHeartBeat), and it's child node is the parameter name of that operation.

I do not have control over the WSDL, so this will not work.

Comment: Is there any reason your using message contract rather than data contract?

Comment: @TomRedfern not really - I'm fairly unfamiliar with the WCF stack. I will try using DataContract attributes and see where I get. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have tried your suggestion and updated the question, @TomRedfern.

Answer (score 0):

After a day's worth of trial and error attempts, I've finally got the deserialisation working correctly.

For *each* of the POCO's members I did the following:

- add an XmlElementAttribute.
- add the Form parameter to XmlElementAttribute, with value of XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified.
- remove the Namespace parameter from the MessageBodyMemberAttribute and add to the XmlElementAttribute.
- removed any existing parameters in MessageBodyMemberAttribute.

Here is the *correct* response POCO:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true,
    WrapperName = "foo_bar_HeartBeatResponse",
    WrapperNamespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/")]
public class HeartBeatResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Namespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/")]
    public string transactionId { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Namespace = "https://foo.com/schemas/fooV1/")]
    public int requestStatus { get; set; }
}
```